# UIDatePicker not rendering properly for certain modes in UIPopoverController

Tags: iphone, ipad, uidatepicker, uidatepickermodetime

I have a `UIDatePicker` using `UIDatePickerModeTime` that I use in an iPhone app modally, works fine:

[image]

Using this same basic code for iPad, but putting the view in a `UIPopoverController` gives some pretty inconsistent results.  My desired mode (`UIDatePickerModeTime`) plus the other three modes are shown below.  Notice how 2 of them are not rendering at all, but instead have no content

`UIDatePickerModeTime`

[image]

`UIDatePickerModeCountDownTimer`

[image]

`UIDatePickerModeDateAndTime`

[image]

`UIDatePickerModeDate`

[image]

What could be causing the `UIDatePickerModeTime` and `UIDatePickerModeDateAndTime` modes to go haywire?

Comment: Are you setting the contentSizeForPopover property in the viewcontroller?

Comment: Yes popoverController.popoverContentSize = self.bounds.size where self is a container view that is the same size as the picker.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Instantiating the `UIDatePicker` with `CGRectZero` was the culprit.  Even though the code worked on iPhone, and I call `sizeToFit` explicitly on it to set the size, changing the `CGRectZero` to `CGRectMake(0,0,320,160)` was what got it to display.  Go figure.